# Problem when using 'sleep' function in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I use `sleep` function in shell script to delay, but it seems not work well.

First, I write the `run_producer.sh` as below:

```
#!/bin/sh
./bin/kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic stressInfluxDB1 \
    --property "parse.key=true" \
    --property "key.separator=:" \
    --property key.schema='{"type":"string"}' \
    --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"measurement","type":"string"},{"name":"id","type":"int"},{
"name":"desc","type":"string"}]}'
```

It requires you to input string like `"keyV":{"measurement": "INFO", "id": 0, "desc": "descriptons"}` in command line when the `run_producer.sh` is executed, and you can input as many as you want. This is not the point.

Then I write the `add_data.sh` as below:

```
cnt=1;
num=20;
while [ $cnt -le $num ]
do
    echo "\"keyV\":{\"measurement\": \"INFO\", \"id\": ${cnt}, \"desc\": \"descri_${cnt}\"}";
    sleep 1s
    ((cnt++))
done | ./run_producer.sh
```

I want to echo 20 times, and delay 1s after each echo. Because I send these data into InfluxDB, so I can get the timestamp as below:

```
time                     desc      id
----                     ----      --
2019-03-25T04:30:16.548Z descri_1  1
2019-03-25T04:30:16.59Z  descri_2  2
2019-03-25T04:30:16.594Z descri_3  3
2019-03-25T04:30:16.598Z descri_4  4
2019-03-25T04:30:16.599Z descri_5  5
2019-03-25T04:30:16.602Z descri_6  6
2019-03-25T04:30:16.604Z descri_7  7
2019-03-25T04:30:16.66Z  descri_8  8
2019-03-25T04:30:17.674Z descri_9  9
2019-03-25T04:30:18.684Z descri_10 10
2019-03-25T04:30:19.701Z descri_11 11
2019-03-25T04:30:20.711Z descri_12 12
2019-03-25T04:30:21.726Z descri_13 13
2019-03-25T04:30:22.735Z descri_14 14
2019-03-25T04:30:23.751Z descri_15 15
2019-03-25T04:30:24.765Z descri_16 16
2019-03-25T04:30:25.774Z descri_17 17
2019-03-25T04:30:26.779Z descri_18 18
2019-03-25T04:30:27.794Z descri_19 19
2019-03-25T04:30:28.8Z   descri_20 20
```

As you can see, the first 8 message are not sent at the interval of 1s.

Why this happen and how can I solve it ?

Comment: Btw.: /bin/sh is usally not bash.

Comment: I suspect there is a buffering issue between the shell loop generating the data and the `./run_producer.sh` script consuming it.  Can you modify the generated data somehow to include a (sub-second?) time stamp for when each row is produced? This would give you a second opinion on when the data is generated for each row. In extremis, add a line `date >&2` after the `echo` and before the `sleep` and look at what it reports.  Usually, `sleep` is an external command, not a shell built-in or a shell function, though it's not hard to build it into a shell.

Comment: Thanks. I found the reason. It is because after `bin/kafka-avro-console-producer` is executed, it needs to wait few seconds to totally run, and then starts receiving data. When it starts receiving data, the `while` already echo some messages, these message were received at the same time, with a very short time. So I add another `sleep 10s` after the first message was sent to wait the command totally run, and it works.